# Extracting hostname for the in the response sub-string beforeXSLT1.0

Tags: xslt, soap, xslt-1.0

I am making the service call to get the session ID from the salesforce and I am trying to extract the hostname from serverurl node.

**Request:** (Basically response from Saleforce)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <loginResponse>
            <result>
                <metadataServerUrl>https://hostname.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/34.0/00Dn00000008evG</metadataServerUrl>
                <passwordExpired>false</passwordExpired>
                <sandbox>true</sandbox>
                <serverUrl>https://hostname.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/34.0/00Dn00000008evG/0DFL000000001Vj</serverUrl>
                <sessionId>00Dn00000008</sessionId>
                <userId>test</userId>

            </result>
        </loginResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am trying to get this value `hostname.my.salesforce.com` from `<serverUrl>https://hostname.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/34.0/00Dn00000008evG/0DFL000000001Vj</serverUrl>`.

I am able the get the value using this

```
<xsl:variable name="serverUrl" select="substring-before(/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='loginResponse']/*[local-name()='result']/*[local-name()='serverUrl'],'/services/Soap/c/34.0/00DS0000003Kwbv/0DFL000000001Vj')"/>
```

The problem is URI part keep changing and rather than matching `/services/Soap/c/34.0/00DS0000003Kwbv/0DFL000000001Vj` is there different way to get the value.

Based on what I have seen it's always this URI first `/services/Soap/c/34.0` and later part changes.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Why not only using `"/services/Soap/c/34.0"` in the `substring-before`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different approach to get the host name only (without leading `https://` would be:

```
select="substring-before( substring-after($servernode, 'https://'), '/')"
```

where servernode is something like

```
<xsl:variable name="servernode" 
    select="*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='loginResponse']/*[local-name()='result']/*[local-name()='serverUrl']"/>
```

By the way I would recommend to avoid using this local-name stuff by using proper namesaces declarations in xslt.

Comment: Thank you! I would go with other approach.